# @IBInspectable fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode8, ibinspectable

I got fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when running my app it hangs for the following code
[image: This is what debugging shows]

Comment: what/where is your `lineHeightConstraint`?

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the Inspectable is triggering your `hasBottomLine` property to be set, and therefore the `didSet` property observer to be called **before** your main view is loaded.

I'm going to guess that your `lineHeightConstraint` is probably defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional, something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lineHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

You'll have to unwrap the optional before using it, for example:

```
lineHeightConstraint?.constant = hasBottomLine ? 3 : 0
```

There may be a chance that you still need to set this constraint after the view is loaded, so you might want to check if the optional contains nil, if so set a flag, and perform this line later in your `viewDidLoad` method. (or perhaps you can just call it regardless in your viewDidLoad)

---

Updated answer, with extra info that this code is in a subclassed UIView rather than UIViewController.

Rather than updating the constraint constant in your `viewDidLoad` method you could do so in the UIView's `layoutSubviews` method. For example:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    lineHeightConstraint?.constant = hasBottomLine ? 3 : 0
}
```

Comment: That removed the error, but the view still not loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the view still not loaded.'  - your viewDidLoad method isn't called? Or the constraint that you're trying to set isn't being set? If the constraint isn't being set you'll want to also set it in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: This code is from HeaderView that is a part of some other views. The views linked to this header are not loaded. So the the app just hang at that point.

Comment: Ah ok, the code is in a subclassed UIView and not a subclassed UIViewController- that is pertinent information. See my answer for an update.